# How to work with .phar file?

Tags: php, phar

I've a .phar file,  how can I open it and modify the content? 
I'm not familiar to this type of file so please explain a step by step solution
I've tried to use a php `$phar->extractto()`  to extract the archive with no results.

Comment: Don't you have the original source that was used to build the phar at all?

Comment: no I only have the .phar file

Comment: `$phar->extractto() to extract the archive with no results.` sounds odd, What actually happened when using this method

Comment: I got this message "Cannot create phar 'it.phar', file extension (or combination) not recognised or the directory does not exist"

Answer (score -1):

If you'd searched for the latter part of your question, "work with .phar file", you'd have found https://cweiske.de/tagebuch/php-phar-files.htm

It tells you that you can use PHP's own `phar` command to extract and re-add files.